# Hello World! with standard segment directives

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

I have written the "Hello World!" code with simplified segment directives,

```
.MODEL small
.STACK
.DATA
msg  DB 'Hello, World!', 0Dh, 0Ah, '$'
.CODE
.STARTUP

LEA DX, msg
MOV ah, 9
INT 21h

MOV ah, 4Ch
INT 21h
END
```

but I must have written something wrong (or miss something) when writing the same thing with standard directive. The code prints a bunch of symbols and only at the end the sentence "Hello World!". What am I missing?

```
myData SEGMENT
msg  DB 'Hello, World!', 0Dh, 0Ah, '$'
myData ENDS

myCode SEGMENT
ASSUME DS:myData, CS:myCode, SS:myStack

LEA DX, msg
MOV ah, 9
INT 21h

MOV ah, 4Ch
INT 21h
myCode ENDS

myStack SEGMENT
myStack ENDS

END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My TASM tells "No entry point", and the garbage chars might indicate missing initialization of data segment, so let's fix both:

```
myData SEGMENT
msg  DB 'Hello, World!', 0Dh, 0Ah, '$'
myData ENDS

myCode SEGMENT
ASSUME DS:myData, CS:myCode, SS:myStack

begin:              ;◄■■ ENTRY POINT ◄────────┐
                                              │
mov ax, myData   ;◄■■ INITIALIZATION          │
mov ds, ax       ;◄■■ OF DATA SEGMENT.        │
                                              │
LEA DX, msg                                   │
MOV ah, 9                                     │
INT 21h                                       │
                                              │
MOV ah, 4Ch                                   │
INT 21h                                       │
myCode ENDS                                   │
                                              │
myStack SEGMENT                               │
myStack ENDS                                  │
                                              │
END begin          ;◄■■ ENTRY POINT ◄─────────┘
```

The "END" directive at the bottom of the code also indicates the point where the program starts to be executed. The initialization of data segment is required in TASM, EMU8086, GUI Turbo Assembler and others where "ASSUME" is not enough.

Comment: Is there a reason why ASSUME is not enough?

Comment: @Nicola, my TASM complains if I don't use assume, it seems to be mandatory for TASM (http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/borland/turbo_assembler/Turbo_Assembler_Version_5_Users_Guide.pdf , page 91), probably for the compiler but not for the linker. Others don't require it, but an all cases initialization of data segment must be done manually.

Comment: @Nicola `assume` doesn't compile to x86 instruction. It's just information to TASM, what did *you* set the segment registers to. So if you say ASSUME ds:dataSeg, and you don't set it, you "lie" to it. Anyway, `int 21h, 9` takes address from `ds:dx`, even if you would code rest of your program with other segment prefixed everywhere.

Comment: How did you create that nice row-spanning arrow? I am really interested how you've done that.

Comment: @zx485 Unicode box-drawing characters. [This one for the horizontal line](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2500/index.htm), and [this one for the vertical line](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2502/index.htm). An em-dash (—) and vertical bar (|) probably would have worked just as well, and are much easier to type.

Comment: @zx485, good old ASCII chars : Alt+17=`◄`, Alt+254=`■`, Alt+196=`─`, Alt+179=`│`, Alt+191=`┐`, Alt+217=`┘`, all of them work in StackOverflow editors, they look a little different when formated as `code` or with ticks before and after.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez: Thank you. It's nice to know that the old ASCII chars are still working.